# VBA Excel loop with solver won´t start a second time

Tags: excel, vba, loops, solver

I have a project where I need to optimize (minimize) costs for heating. The optimization should run for the first 48 rows, then copy the first values of certain parameters und use them as start condition for the second optimization and so on:

```
Sub MPCMacro()
'
' 
'

   Dim i As Integer
   ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate
   
   For i = 0 To 1 ' Will later be 336; Just trying to check if it starts a second time
      
    
        
        SolverOk SetCell:=("52 + 48 * i, 42"), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, 
        ByChange:="(5 + 48 * i, 31):(52 + 48 * i, 31)" _
        , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        
        SolverAdd cellRef:="(5 + 48 * i, 31):(52 + 48 * i, 31)", _
        relation:=1, _
        formulaText:=4
        SolverAdd cellRef:="(5 + 48 * i, 31):(52 + 48 * i, 31)", _
        relation:=3, _
        formulaText:=0

        SolverSolve True 
        SolverSolve userfinish:=True
        SolverFinish keepFinal:=1
        
      'Copy start condition 1
        Cells(6 + 48 * i, 29).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Cells(5 + 48 * (i + 1), 29).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
      
      'Copy start condition 2
        Cells(6 + 48 * i, 34).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Cells(5 + 48 * (i + 1), 34).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        'SolverReset; usually you would place SolverReset here but it won´t even start if I do
      
   Next i
     
End Sub
```

My problem is, that the solver starts his first run and gives me perfectly plausable results, but it won´t start a second time. There is no error message or anything. The copy function does it´s job for all loops, so I guess there is no problem with the loop. Is there an error in my Solver setup?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your referencing of _SetCell_ and _cellRef_ looks wrong. This should be a range not a String e.g. `SetCell:=Cells(52 + 48 * i, 42)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try deactivating Solver and reactivating  with `AddIns("Solver").Installed = False` and later True again?